# Is there a way to pass a Python variable into an SQL Query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to pass the result of a user input into an SQL query, like so:

```
def select_rows(conn):
    table_choice = input("Choose a table: ")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", table_choice)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

but I get this Error:

```
Database Path: C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\SQL\chinook.db
Choose a table: album
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\SQL\SQL.py", line 27, in <module>
    select_rows(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Desktop\SQL\SQL.py", line 20, in select_rows
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", table_choice)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't parameterize table names. You need to format them into the query

Answer (score 2):

You can use f-string as well:

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_choice}")
```

But be careful with user's input and query. You should write a function to validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

you need to format the query before executing it...:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_choice))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", (table_choice,))
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this was downvoted? The sqlite3 documentation seems to support this syntax. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html